# Python MultiProcessing PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'c_ubyte_Array_4_Array_84_Array_84'>

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle

I am getting the error message:

PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'c_ubyte_Array_4_Array_84_Array_84'>: attribute lookup c_ubyte_Array_4_Array_84_Array_84 on **main** failed

when running the RAINBOW example:

https://github.com/cmusjtuliuyuan/RainBow

I cannot find any relevant information on the issue on line. Does anybody know how to fix it?

-- what object is causing the issue?

-- why this happen, it is quite evolved example, seems well written, thus seems odd it happens to me.

-- I read that using dill instead of pickle might help with such issues but multiprocesing requires pickle it seems.

Thx!